# ActionEventHandler JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a question: is there any possibility to set a `Button`'s eventHandler to fire/trigger another `Button`'s eventHandler?

Say `buttonA`'s eventHandler is to fire/trigger `buttonC`'s eventHandler.
If yes, would appreciate if anyone could provide some sample.
I am currently facing problem because I can't close the stage2 from the other button (I think highly due to visibility of the class)

```
button4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
        stage1.close();
        **stage2**.setScene(scene);
        **stage2**.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using [`fire`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#fire--):

```
Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
button1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Button 1 pressed!"));

Button button2 = new Button("Button 2");
button2.setOnAction(e -> {
    System.out.println("Button 2 pressed! Pressing Button 1 ...");
    button1.fire();
});
```

*Output*

```
Button 2 pressed! Pressing Button 1 ...
Button 1 pressed!
```

But this approach is not the suggested one. You could encapsulate the contents of the handler into a method, what you can call in the handlers directly:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
button1.setOnAction(e -> actionToBeDone());

Button button2 = new Button("Button 2");
button2.setOnAction(e -> {
    System.out.println("Things done on Button 2 press");
    actionToBeDone();
});
```

and the method

```
private void actionToBeDone(){
    System.out.println("Things done on Button 1 press");
}
```

*Output*

```
Things done on Button 2 press
Things done on Button 1 press
```

Comment: Hmmm.... I will give it a try. Cause at the moment I am trying to reuse the same button in different layer of button and eventHandler

Comment: I think I got confused myself. I actually wanted to trigger the same button in the different stage that has the same button. For example: When I am on the main page of an application, I wanted to go to a new stage (Print Report) in that stage I wanted to click the button of Manage User(button) which already exists in the main page(main stage) How do I trigger that event by clicking the same button? LOL... I am sorry if I confuse you guys.

Comment: If you have controllers (you should have) for the different stages, you can expose the mentioned method in the controller, then you can call the method from the first controller. The methodology is the same.

Comment: reason being I reuse the same button but I am not sure how to make to the button to function.

**button4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent e){
       stage1.close();
       button4.fire(); //**button4 has already exist in the main stage.**

Comment: Without seeing your structure it is nearly impossible to tell more that I answered and commented. You could update the question with all of the code you have in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).